# How do you keep Netbeans 8.0 from rebuilding every file?

Tags: c++, windows, netbeans, makefile

For all of my c++ projects using netbeans, whenever I make a single small change the entire project is rebuilt. There must be a way to prevent this.

My build logs ends up looking like this:

```
mkdir -p build/Debug/CLang-Windows/_ext/237546996
rm -f "build/Debug/CLang-Windows/_ext/237546996/Sensor.o.d"
clang++ -g -std=gnu++11   -c -g -DSFML_STATIC -I/C/Users/izack_000/Documents/Programming/Projects/SynapseCpp/SFML/extlibs/headers/libsndfile/windows -I/C/Users/izack_000/Documents/Programming/Projects/SynapseCpp/SFML/extlibs/headers/libfreetype/windows -I/C/Users/izack_000/Documents/Programming/Projects/SynapseCpp/SFML/extlibs/headers -I/C/Users/izack_000/Documents/Programming/Projects/SynapseCpp/SFML/extlibs/headers/jpeg -I/C/Users/izack_000/Documents/Programming/Projects/SynapseCpp/SFML/extlibs/headers/AL -I../SFML/src -I../SFML/include -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/CLang-Windows/_ext/237546996/Sensor.o.d" -o build/Debug/CLang-Windows/_ext/237546996/Sensor.o ../SFML/src/SFML/Window/Sensor.cpp
mkdir -p build/Debug/CLang-Windows/_ext/237546996
rm -f "build/Debug/CLang-Windows/_ext/237546996/SensorManager.o.d"
clang++ -g -std=gnu++11   -c -g -DSFML_STATIC -I/C/Users/izack_000/Documents/Programming/Projects/SynapseCpp/SFML/extlibs/headers/libsndfile/windows -I/C/Users/izack_000/Documents/Programming/Projects/SynapseCpp/SFML/extlibs/headers/libfreetype/windows -I/C/Users/izack_000/Documents/Programming/Projects/SynapseCpp/SFML/extlibs/headers -I/C/Users/izack_000/Documents/Programming/Projects/SynapseCpp/SFML/extlibs/headers/jpeg -I/C/Users/izack_000/Documents/Programming/Projects/SynapseCpp/SFML/extlibs/headers/AL -I../SFML/src -I../SFML/include -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/CLang-Windows/_ext/237546996/SensorManager.o.d" -o build/Debug/CLang-Windows/_ext/237546996/SensorManager.o ../SFML/src/SFML/Window/SensorManager.cpp
mkdir -p build/Debug/CLang-Windows/_ext/237546996
rm -f "build/Debug/CLang-Windows/_ext/237546996/Touch.o.d"
clang++ -g -std=gnu++11   -c -g -DSFML_STATIC -I/C/Users/izack_000/Documents/Programming/Projects/SynapseCpp/SFML/extlibs/headers/libsndfile/windows -I/C/Users/izack_000/Documents/Programming/Projects/SynapseCpp/SFML/extlibs/headers/libfreetype/windows -I/C/Users/izack_000/Documents/Programming/Projects/SynapseCpp/SFML/extlibs/headers -I/C/Users/izack_000/Documents/Programming/Projects/SynapseCpp/SFML/extlibs/headers/jpeg -I/C/Users/izack_000/Documents/Programming/Projects/SynapseCpp/SFML/extlibs/headers/AL -I../SFML/src -I../SFML/include -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/CLang-Windows/_ext/237546996/Touch.o.d" -o build/Debug/CLang-Windows/_ext/237546996/Touch.o ../SFML/src/SFML/Window/Touch.cpp
```

As as you can see the object files are being removed before generating new files. Is there a setting for this or do I have to change the makefiles generated by netbeans?

Or perhaps there is something I accidentally turned on? (always clean?) Though I don't think its likely because its happening for both of my projects.

Edit: this seems to only happens on windows

Comment: According to this webpage: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/depchecking.html it should not being doing this.

Comment: There are no `clang++` in the list of supported toolchains for Windows - https://netbeans.org/community/releases/80/cpp-setup-instructions.html

Comment: Usually when you right click a project name and go to properties there is an option called "Build on Save" you can uncheck that option